# d3 dependency loading before d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using a d3 word cloud service that requires d3 to be loaded before it in order to load properly.  Thus, in my `services.js` page, I load d3 before the word cloud service.

This works most of the time.  However, occasionally, the word cloud won't load properly and I'll get the error:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined  (localhost:8080/lib/d3-word-cloud.js:400)**

Is this because the services aren't loading in the proper order?  What can I do to correct this?

EDIT:  Code below:

```
myApp.factory('d3Service', ['$document', '$window', '$q', '$rootScope',
  function ($document, $window, $q, $rootScope) {
    var d = $q.defer(),
    d3service = {
      d3: function() { return d.promise; }
    };
    function onScriptLoad() {
        // Load client in the browser
        $rootScope.$apply(function() { d.resolve($window.d3); });
    }
    var scriptTag = $document[0].createElement('script');
    scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    scriptTag.async = true;
    scriptTag.src = 'http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js';
    scriptTag.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 'complete') onScriptLoad();
    }
    scriptTag.onload = onScriptLoad;

    var s = $document[0].getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    s.appendChild(scriptTag);

    return d3service;
}]);

myApp.factory('d3Cloud', ['$document', '$window', '$q', '$rootScope',
  function ($document, $window, $q, $rootScope) {
    var d = $q.defer(),
    d3cloud = {
      cloud: function() { return d.promise; }
    };
    function onScriptLoad() {
        // Load client in the browser
        $rootScope.$apply(function() { d.resolve($window.d3); });
    }
    var scriptTag = $document[0].createElement('script');
    scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    scriptTag.async = true;
    scriptTag.src = '../lib/d3-word-cloud.js';
    scriptTag.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 'complete') onScriptLoad();
    }
    scriptTag.onload = onScriptLoad;

    var s = $document[0].getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    s.appendChild(scriptTag);

    return d3cloud;
}]);
```

Comment: It sounds like it could be an asynchronous loading issue...could you post some code?  Preferably a minimal proof-of-concept example....

Comment: Hm...I wonder if you're not getting in trouble by marking the script async (`scriptTag.async = true`)...perhaps it's inserting the script, and sometimes the browser isn't processing in time....

Comment: I'll test it out and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it can be, but a workaround could be to check `typeof d3` before using it (and wait or reload it if not).

if is a web page why not load d3 on `<script>` and use a ready/onload method instead of doing it dynamically ?

Comment: I would do that, load D3 on the HTML code should work with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

So I guess you want to do the following at app startup:

```js
angular.module('d3CloudApp', [])
  .run(['d3Service', 'd3Cloud', function(d3Service, d3Cloud){
    d3Service.d3()
      .then(function(d3){
        d3Cloud.cloud();
      })
  })]
```

Should work :-) Having said that your second resolve inside d3Cloud is probably wrong:

```js
d.resolve($window.d3);
```

Should be something like:

```js
d.resolve($window.d3Word);
```